# Using django ImageField with Tastypie

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

I am trying to store images on my backend that I can reference with an ImageField in able to link Users with a headshot. I haven't had any luck with documentation on how to do this in TastyPie.

What are the minimum viable steps I need to take to get an image from my backend displaying on an html webpage?

Here is my code of what I have been trying at:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    headshot = models.ImageField()
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**api.py**

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie import fields
from blog.models import User

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    headshot = fields.FileField(attribute='headshot', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'users'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from tastypie.api import Api

from blog.api import UserResource

blog = Api(api_name='v1')
blog.register(UserResource())

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include(blog.urls))
]
```

- My media folder is located in my project directory (same as settings.py)

test image location--> /myproject/media/images/nickbrady.jpg

- api.py is inside my django app (same as models.py)
- Urls and models are in their standard django locations

I created my user object like this:

```
User.objects.create(name='Nick Brady', headshot='images/nickbrady.jpg')
```

and my current API response is this:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "limit": 20,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 1
  },
  "objects": [
    {
      "headshot": "/media/images/nickbrady.jpg",
      "id": 1,
      "img": null,
      "name": "Nick Brady",
      "resource_uri": "/blog/v1/users/1/"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/nickbrady.jpg
```

or many other combinations adding blog/v1/media, etc. I am not able to see the image through a browser or html page.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? I've had a really hard time finding documentation on how to do this in tastypie

Comment: What error you are getting while opening this url in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be your problem:

```
User.objects.create(name='Nick Brady', headshot='images/nickbrady.jpg')
```

Unless that file is already in that location within your storage, it won't actually reference your file.

You probably want to wrap a file object in this class and save that instead of a string: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/file/

On save that file will get copied to your storage directory.

Comment: Sean, thank you for your response. I will try this out tomorrow and do some research on the storage directory.. that sounds like a nice new fish to follow as well. I won't forget to accept as answer if this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided details of your error, so i can just **guess** what's wrong!so if you provide more details I'll delete it if it is wrong!
maybe the problem is that you haven't set [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root) in your `settings.py` file like bellow:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Hi @iman-mirzadeh, it is a 404 error. I saw what you mentioned somewhere else and tried it to to avail. I added it in again and you specified and was not able to see the image in the browser. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I did some digging into the documentation with the help of the other two answers and was able to find a solution.

I had to change:
urls.py to:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static  # Added this line
from django.contrib import admin

from tastypie.api import Api

from blog.api import UserResource

blog = Api(api_name='v1')
blog.register(UserResource())

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include(blog.urls))
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  # And this
```

I added MEDIA_ROOT to settings as Iman suggested to **settings.py**:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/media/'  # Added this
```

And when I created my User object, I took advice from Sean (which was required) to wrap the file object in a django file class when creating my User object. [I used the image class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/file/#the-imagefile-class) which is a thin wrapper on the django file class.

from the *./manage.py shell* it would look like this.

```
>>> from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
>>> img_file = open('path/to/file.jpg', 'rb')  # 'rb' --> read as bytes since image
>>> django_wrapped_img = ImageFile(img_file)
>>> User.objects.create(name='Nick Brady', headshot=django_wrapped_img)
```

After creating an object this way, the image was copied to where my MEDIA_ROOT was specified.

After I did this, I was abled to successfully see my image from Postman.

NOTE: At this point, it would be more proper to use a static_url and root as opposed to media since I am putting my content directly onto the backend. Media is meant more to handle user uploads I have discovered. Since that is my future intention, I am leaving it like this.

Comment: You should put `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in an if statement that only runs when `DEBUG = True`, you won't want to use that method in production.